# Multi-column IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I've written a bit of pseudocode to try and summarise what I'm trying to do, and am currently struggling with the returning bit of the problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocvFW.png)

***If value of cell (A2) is found in cells (D2:D42):***

***X = row number of cell in which value of (A2) was found***

***Print in cell (E2) the value of cell (E X)***

I can do the first line, the actual IF statement, but it's then returning the value of the cell in column E in the row in which the value of A2 was found. Convoluted, I know. Anyway, how can I do this?

Comment: Sounds like `VLOOKUP()` or similar concepts.

Comment: You have to be more precise: Will value of A2 occure exactly once or propably multiple times within D2:D42?

Comment: To be honest, with the work I'm doing in Excel, I don't know. Might appear never, once, or multiple.

Comment: Then: if it appears multiple times - should the result go into one cell (E2) e.g. concatenated? Or would you expect each result in a single cell?

Comment: If you are using office 365 make use of FILTER function to have the list of all values found in your D2:D42.

Comment: The results would all go into one cell, but since I know the data in the relevant cells is going to be the same (i.e. train stock types), it doesn't need to be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you just need the row number of the value of A2 in range D2:D42. So, this should work:

`=MATCH(A2;D2:D42;0)+1`